# Books on n-dimensional euclidian geometry?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question

Could anyone please recommend some books on n-dimensional Euclidean geometry? Thanks!

Comment: You can look at any Linear Algebra text book.

Comment: For example [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Through-Geometry-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387975861).

Comment: @begeistzwerst, thanks, it looks very nice.